# wp_schedule_single_event never executes

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem that makes no sense to me.

I striped the code down to minimum code but the cron job never fires.

```
function do_this_cron() {
    file_put_contents('/home/vagrant/Code/wordpress/test.log', "schedule event run\n", FILE_APPEND);

}
add_action( 'my_new_event', 'do_this_cron' );

$time = time() + MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * 2;
$ret = wp_schedule_single_event($time, 'my_new_event');
var_dump($ret) // always returns true
```

I have a cron manager plugin installed which lets me run the cron manually, but even there i can execute the job but it never runs the function.

Anyone have any ideas why this is not running?

Comment: Have you checked if error_log('Cron firing'); or something like that works?

Comment: Have you checked inside your wp-config if u have define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true'); because that would kill WP cron scheduler

Comment: just tried error_log, nothing there either.

Comment: DISABLE_WP_CRON is not in the config file

Comment: Do you have wp-cron.php in your root folder ? because this sound so weird >:

Comment: yes i have the wp_cron.php in the root folder. I am running this on a fresh install of wordpress also.

Comment: it seems the error_log and the file_put_contents dont work, but sending a email does work